# Do I have 2 more free slots for RAM?

Tags: 16.04, ram

I ran `sudo dmidecode --type memory` and the result was:

```
# dmidecode 3.0
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x000C, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000C
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MHz
    Manufacturer: Hynix/Hyundai
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number:                   
    Rank: 1
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000C
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 1
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: [Empty]
    Serial Number: [Empty]
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: [Empty]
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000C
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MHz
    Manufacturer: Hynix/Hyundai
    Serial Number: 3480B4B3
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: HMT451S6BFR8A-PB  
    Rank: 1
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000C
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 3
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: [Empty]
    Serial Number: [Empty]
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: [Empty]
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
```

I see that there are 2 with 4096 MB and 2 without informations, that means I can add 2 more RAM kit or I have to replace those 2?

Comment: Please remember that some computers are sold with missing RAM slots, which are recognized by dmidecode anyway. I had this with an Acer Aspire E1 laptop recently - the system detected two slots, and then I ordered another 4 GB of RAM for the second slot. Well, only one slot was there and the only way to upgrade was ordering 8 GB for the first (and only) slot.

Comment: So what you're saying is even if I run this command `sudo dmidecode -t memory | grep -c '^Memory Device$'` which is saying how many slots I have, it's possible to not have? That's bad.

Comment: If you tell us the make and model of your PC we can lookit it up. It will also be in the user manual.

Comment: Yes, it's possible that the system detects two slots, but only one is installed. Might be a problem in lower-end computers like mine, where they cut corners in order to offer a cheaper product. As Steve said, look it up in the manual, or tell us the exact model name (though the model designation was misleading in my case, and most websites indicated two RAM slots).

Comment: Can you open the case and look?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to get the exact model of your machine like so:

`sudo dmidecode | grep "System Information" -A 3`

then go to a retail site like http://crucial.com and search their database for upgrade options.